# Происхождение слова "хабалить"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

В недавнем прошлом шалуна ребенка одергивали: "Перестань хабалить!". Что значит слово "хабалить"? Как оно произошло?

Answer (score 3):

"Хабалить" - это волжский диалект, он означает "ругать", "бранить" и даже "наглеть". Происходит от слова "хабал", "хабальный" с тем же значением "нахал", "буян", "наглец" и т. д.
Есть еще слово "хабальница" - то, что мы сейчас называем "базарная баба", то есть крикливая, скандальная тетка.

Comment: Даль дает более широкую географию глагола, не чисто волжскую: вологодские, пермяцкие, курские диалекты